# Verify data in JOptionPane before it is closed

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, joptionpane

I have a `JOptionPane` in which I have a `JPanel` with some text fields. When you click on "ok" something should happen with the values of the text fields. But before something happen, I want to check if a text field is empty. If so the dialog should not dismiss and I want to show a message that all fields are required.

If I do it like this:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, dialogPanel, "Neuen Kunden anlegen", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    ...
}
```

the dialog is already dismissed when I check the pressed button. Is it possible to handle the button click before the dialog dismiss?

Answer (score 2):

A JOptionPane's button press will close the dialog -- you can't change that. And so your options are to either re-show the JOptionPane or create and display your own modal JDialog and have their button's listeners behave as you desire.